# CSS files are not loading :

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

I am trying to learn thymeleaf. I am doing so by referencing the "petclinic spring project". I was able to create a html page with thymeleaf tags. I am able to load the java scripts but not able to load the css files. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

below is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:ddl="http://www.thymeleaf.org/dandelion"
      xmlns:dt="http://github.com/dandelion/datatables"
      ddl:bundle-includes="bootstrap3"
      lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<title th:text="#{app.title}">Niti</title>

<link href="../static/css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"  rel="stlyesheet" />
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stlyesheet" />
<link href="../static/css/jquery-ui.min.css" th:href="@{/css/jquery-ui.min.css}" rel="stlyesheet" />
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css}" rel="stlyesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" th:src="@{/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery-ui.min.js"  th:src="@{/js/jquery-ui.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"  th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</head>


<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        sec:authorize="!isAnonymous()" class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" th:text="#{app.title}">Application Name </a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="../welcome.html" th:href="@{/}">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../timesheets.html" th:href="@{/timesheets.html}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> TimeSheets</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../expense.html" th:href="@{/expense.html}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Expense</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../exception.html" th:href="@{/oups.html}" title="trigger a RuntimeException to see how it is handled">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Error</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="../social.html" th:href="@{/social}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Inbox</a>
                    </li>
                    <li sec:authorize="!isAnonymous()"><a href="../logout" th:href="|#|"
                        th:onclick="|javascript:if (confirm('Are you sure you want to log out?')) { window.location.href = '@{/logout}'} else { return false; }|"
                        title="Logout"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Logout  </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

below is my project structure.

[image]

When I browse localhost:8080 and hit developer tools, i dont see css loading i just see the javascript files loaded. for CSS files I do not even see the error.

[image]
can some one let me know what wrong i am doing ?

Comment: Any luck using absolute file paths?

Comment: Perhaps change `rel="stlyesheet"` to `rel="stylesheet"`. Also you don't need to close `<link>` tags.

Comment: @Mark_M nice catch on that typo

Comment: Does it come up as not found in your console?  Are you trying to override bootstrap styles because your main.css file should be loaded after your bootstrap css files otherwise it will have no effect.

Comment: oh my god. you are an angel to me @mark_m . I cannot tell you how much time i spent on this. Thank you so much Mark.. u might want to post that as an answer for me to accept it. On another note, do we have any plugins to catch such type of typos ? .. thanks a bunch for this.

Comment: Wow hahaha - I think you just found that plugin @user641887, and his name is Mark_M